# JAVA-Maneira correta de não ler a tecla enter

Tags: java, scanner

Estou fazendo o problema 1168 - LED e gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de fazer com que meu `in.nextLine()` não leia a tecla enter,consegui fazendo criando uma variável para ler este enter,mas tenho certeza que não é a forma mais correta de fazer isso.

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1168 (problema do uri para quem quiser ver,aceito sugestões na melhora do codigo também).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uri1168 {
    public static void main(String[]args){

    int i,n;
    int total = 0;
    String enter;


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = in.nextInt();

    enter = in.nextLine();
    for(i = 0;n>i;n--){
        total = 0;

    String v;
    v = in.nextLine();
    char[] num = v.toCharArray();

    for (char c : num) { // divide o numero em cada numero separado
        int f = Integer.parseInt(c+"");
        if (f==1){
            total += 2;
        }else if (f==2){
            total += 5;
        }else if (f==3){
            total += 5;
        }else if (f==4){
            total += 4;
        }else if (f==5){
            total += 5;
        }else if (f==6){
            total += 6;
        }else if (f==7){
            total += 3;
        }else if (f==8){
            total += 7;
        }else if (f==9){
            total += 6;
        }else if (f==0){
            total += 6;
        }




    }
    System.out.println(total+" leds\n");
    }

    in.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Desculpe fechar sua pergunta como duplicata, mas lá na pergunta que linkei (juntamente com as respectivas respostas), ele explica o porquê desse problema que você está tendo.

Comment: Sobre a melhoria do código, sugiro dar uma olhada na estrutura `switch` ao invés do `if`

Comment: Ou melhor ainda, ao invés de `switch` ou `if`, use uma tabela na forma de um array para encontrar os números a serem somados. `int[] tabela = {6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6}; total += tabela[f];` - CC @Tuxpilgrim

Comment: Beleza Victor,irei dar uma olhada. Obrigado,nao tinha achado.
Obrigado tambem  Tuxpilgrim ,o switch realmente é melhor